# Custom dropdown selector

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I'm working on improving my knowledge of OOP in JS. I just created this [custom dropdown selector](http://codepen.io/alonsogarciapablo/pen/MYEOpE). It's working nicely, but I'm not super happy about the `Filter` constructor. I would like to make all that code more readable. It's basically just defining some attributes and setting some event listeners.

```
function Filter(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.dropdown = this.element.querySelector('.dropdown');

  var link = this.element.querySelector('.link');
  var options = this.dropdown.querySelectorAll('a');

  var selectOption = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    link.textContent = event.target.textContent;
    this.toggle();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].addEventListener('click', selectOption.bind(this));
  }

  link.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));
};

Filter.prototype.isExpanded = function() {
  return !this.dropdown.classList.contains('hidden');
}

Filter.prototype.collapse = function() {
  if (this.isExpanded()) {
    this.dropdown.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}

Filter.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (!this.isExpanded()) {
    var filterExpandedEvent = new CustomEvent('filterExpanded', {detail: this});
    document.dispatchEvent(filterExpandedEvent);
  }

  this.dropdown.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

How you would you simplify that constructor? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you verify that your link to the custom dropdown selector is valid?

Answer (score 2):

## Public versus private fields

In Java, it is a custom to make all your fields private, unless they **must** be explicitly accessed by other sources. I believe this custom also applies to JavaScript.

Instead of having the `element` be a public (`this`) field, why don't you make it a private (`var`) field? There doesn't really seem to be another place you use it.

And, if there is another place that on using it in, why don't you create a `get`ter? This would be a function that returns the field, and it might be named something like `getElement`.

This is up to you.

## Defining the functions with `Filter.prototype`

You did exactly this, and that is perfect. Keep that up, it is a great practice.

## `querySelector` versus `getElementsByClassName`

This is a matter of efficiency versus readability - whatever you chose to have.

It would be more efficient to use `getElementsByClassName` in place of `querySelector` in the `link` field, as the `getElementsByClassName` function doesn't have to do checks on the argument provided(whether or not the argument is a class, an id, a tag name, or a mixture); it knows it's looking for a one class and one class only.

It is slightly more readable having `querySelector`, as the syntax for it's arguments is the same syntax for CSS; it's a "universal" syntax.

## Indentation

With only 2 spaces for an indent, your code looks fairly cramped. I recommend using tabs or 4 spaces as an indent.